# Jquery показать вложенную таблицу при клике по tr

Tags: jquery

Имеется следующий макет

```
 <table>
    <tbody>                                     
       <tr class="lessons-row">
         <td class="text-center"> данные</td>   
       </tr>
       <table class="table-users">
         <tbody>                                                
          <tr>
           <td class="text-center">данные юзеря</td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Таблица `class="table-users"` вложена в другую таблицу и имеет свойство `display:none`. Как при клике по `class="lessons-row"` (строчка родительской таблицы) показать вложенную таблицу. Обязательно с помощью оператора `this` так как так строчек с таблицами может быть множество.

Пробую делать так , но это не работает

```
$(".lessons-row").on('click',function() {
            var table_users = $(this).next('.table-users');
      //Отображаем скрытый блок
            if (table_users.css('display') == 'none'){
        table_users.animate({height: 'show'}, 500);
      } else {
        table_users.animate({height: 'hide'}, 500);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас невалидная разметка, и если бы Вы открыли отладчик, то увидели бы, что браузер отрисовал DOM не так, как Вам хотелось - по факту получаются две независимые таблицы, которые идут друг за другом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы сделать вложенную таблицу, её надо поместить в ячейку следующей строки. Но тогда, во-первых, возникает вопрос, нужна ли Вам вообще вложенная таблица, если всё равно это будет просто строка родительской таблицы? А, во-вторых, скрывать целесообразнее не вложенную таблицу, а саму следующую строку. И тогда Ваш код будет работать:

```js
$(".lessons-row").on('click',function() {
  var table_users = $(this).next('.table-users');
  //Отображаем скрытый блок
  if (table_users.css('display') == 'none'){
    table_users.animate({height: 'show'}, 500);
  } else {
    table_users.animate({height: 'hide'}, 500);
  }
});
```

```css
.table-users {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>                                     
       <tr class="lessons-row">
         <td class="text-center"> данные</td>   
       </tr>
       <tr class="table-users">
         <td>
         <table>
           <tbody>                                                
            <tr>
             <td class="text-center">данные юзеря</td>
            </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Осознал и исправил, спасибо!)